# Using Flutter bloc to set loading state during API call

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am learning flutter_bloc and now i am aware now about it.I know how it used when fetching some data from server and then showing in widgets let's suppose list of items.
But i want to know how can i show loading indicator while making API call which is simple like increment quantity of item in cart.
I means it should work something like this.You click a icon and it calls a function which increment quantity of the item by an API call.
Now in that i want to fire event to ApiBloc which change it state to loading true and after the API call is done ApiBloc will change state to loading false.
And in my screen when loadimg is true i want to show the Loading indicator and as the bloc changes loading to false then Loading indicator will be disappread.
Please help me with this.